# Pass Jenkins Log File to the a web service

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins, hudson-api

I am working on a requirement I need to pass the log file of the job to a web service after the build step

I would like to know

1. What are the plugins available to call a web service after the build which would facilitate me to pass the log file.

I am getting the path of the log file using:

$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/$JOB_NAME/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/log

how to send the contents of it via HTTP Post

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to pass it? IS ssh available? IF it is you could ssh into the web server and copy the file as part of your jenkins script.

OR

To do a http post use this plugin.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTTP+POST+Plugin

Comment: I want to pass it to a REST  service which would accept XML data as a input and process it and store results in DB. I have Use HTTP Post but i am not getting a way to pass the console log out put to my service. I am calling http://localhost:55223/api/Demo/Post?URI=$BUILD_URL/consolelog